# How Can I Connect virtual networks from different deployment models using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-virtual-network

I googled and searched but no use. I have VNet which is already created in Azure Classic Portal and I want to add a subnet gateway and a gateway in PowerShell to connect it to an existing IaaS v2 Vnet. How can I do that in PowerShell? Please let me know if there's any resources on how to do that.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, if you want to connect the VNets in different deployment models. The most important is that, the address ranges for the VNets do not overlap with each other, or overlap with any of the ranges for other connections that the gateways may be connected to.

Also your PC have installed the last PowerShell cmdlets, make sure you install both the Service Management (ASM) and the Resource Manager (ARM) cmdlets. Now we can create the VPN to connect the VNets in different deployment models.

More information about how to connect VNets in different deployment models, please refer to the link below:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-connect-different-deployment-models-powershell/

If you still have questions, welcome to post back here. Thanks.